# iOS project not seeing local changes when developing a Cocoapod project

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm working on a framework that is available via Cocoapods.

I have my project set up using their suggested setup, and their development page says "You can work on the library from its folder on your system." but when I make changes to the files in the "Development Pods" folder and build my project, the changes do not show up.

I've tried running `$ pod install` on the project, which regenerates the xcworkspace file, but the changes still don't show up. I'm unsure how the changes are being missed, as I've commented out a large chunk of code and added a few NSLogs, but it still runs as if I never made the changes.

I've also tried cleaning the project via xcode.

Any ideas?

Bonus q: What is the correct way to work on a cocoapod framework? The documentation is rather lacking when it comes to setting up a project like this.

Edit: Here's the podfile:

```
platform :ios, "6.0"
pod "MyFramework", :path => "../"
```

(using an example name as the pod is't published yet)

Comment: Do you mean your changes are not visible to the code that uses your library? Is this another project in the same workspace where you have your framework code, or is it separate?

Comment: Yes, the project doesn't see the updated code in the included pod. It is a demo project in the same folder as the pod files, and the pod files are included via a `:path` directive. As a test, I created a public method `testLog` and built the project. It was able to build without errors, but throws an unrecognized selector exception when I try to call the new method.

Comment: So which of the two setups do you have: (1) just one copy of the framework code, included in the same workspace as your test app; or (2) your test app using the framework as a pod (a copy of the library is pulled into your workspace by the pod script)?

Comment: Never mind: just saw the edit to your post.

Comment: It's possible I messed up the dependencies in my build rules somehow. I had to rename the project at one point.

Should the `Pods` target be included under my build targets? (I tried adding it, but I get a new warning about i386 architecture missing.

Comment: When you run `pod install` are you even able successfully add the frameworks to your workspace?  You have have quotes in your podfile where you should have grave accents ( ` ).

Comment: Yeah `pod install` seems to run fine, and it generates the xcworkspace.

Ok so I just tried deleting the xcworkspace and running `pod install` again and that seems to have fixed it. The only thing I can tell is different is that `Pods` is now listed as a build target in my app's scheme. And the changes are showing up now. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix was to delete my xcworkspace [`rm -rf MyFramework.xcworkspace`] and recreate it via `pod install`.

The only difference I can see is that `Pods` is now included in the build targets for my demo app's scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general process for developing a cocoapod.

1. Run `pod lib create <Pod Name>` to create your project.

   ```
   cd MyDirectory
   pod lib create MyPod
   ```
2. Make sure to run `pod install` inside your example project. This will generate a `.xcworkspace` file.

   ```
   cd MyPod/Example
   pod install
   ```
3. Open your example project via the `.xcworkspace` file.

   `Xcode -> File -> Open -> MyPod.xcworkspace`
4. Edit your pod via `Pods/Development Pods`.

   `Project Navigator -> Pods -> Development Pods -> MyPod -> <file>`
5. Clean, build, & run your example project.

   **Make sure to clean (cmd+shift+k)** your project before running, otherwise changes made to your pod will not be captured.